# How to Cycle Through Background Colors on Hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to make a div that cycles through background colors when hovered over with the mouse. I've figured out how to make the background color switch to a color value from a set of values on `mouseenter`, but not how to make it keep going.

How do I make the background color keep changing while the mouse is hovered over the element (and stop once I've moused out)?

Here's a fully working fiddle of what I have so far: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QRkEc/)

My HTML:

```
<body>  
    <div id="coloredDiv" data-index="-1"></div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
#coloredDiv {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #888;
}

#coloredDiv:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

My jQuery:

```
var colors = ['#eeeeee', "#00ff00", "#ff0000", "#000000"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $colorDiv = $('#coloredDiv');
    ln = colors.length;
    $('#coloredDiv').mouseenter( function () {
        var i = $colorDiv.data("index");
        ++i;
        if (i >= ln) i = 0;
        $colorDiv.css({
            'background-color': colors[i]
        });
        $colorDiv.data("index", i);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.shift` and `Array.push` to make cycle happen

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pC7vs/)

```
var counter = 0;
var colors = [
    "#eeeeee",
    "#00ff00",
    "#ff0000",
    "#000000"];

var $div = $('#coloredDiv');

$('#coloredDiv').mouseenter(function () {
    var color = colors.shift(); //Get the top color
    colors.push(color); //push it to the end for the cycle to repeat.
    $div.css({
        "background-color": color
    })

});
```

For cycle to repeat on hover:-

```
var counter = 0;
var colors = [
    "#eeeeee",
    "#00ff00",
    "#ff0000",
    "#000000"];

var $div = $('#coloredDiv');
var interval;
$('#coloredDiv').mouseenter(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(changeColor, 1000); //set the interval of 1 sec for image to change while hovered.

}).mouseleave(function () {
    window.clearInterval(interval); //clear the interval on mouseOut.
});

function changeColor() {
    var color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);
    $div.css({
        "background-color": color
    });

}
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xPqd/)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- this doesn't seem to work in the Fiddle.

Comment: @DannyCooper See my update... I missed out the cycle to keep happen on hover thing.

Comment: Works great! I added a line of code to fire off the function immediately on `mouseenter`--and then in intervals after that--instead of having to wait the interval for the first background color change: http://jsfiddle.net/rP8VK/

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
  var element = $('#id');
  var colors = ['#eeeeee', "#00ff00", "#ff0000", "#000000"];
  var idx = 0;
  var timer;

  function changeColor() {
    element.css('background-color', colors[idx++ % colors.length]);
  }

  element.hover(
    // start hover

    function() {
      idx = 0;
      changeColor();
      timer = setInterval(changeColor, 250);
    },

    // end hover

    function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      element.css('background-color', '');
    }
  );
}());
```