# How to cycle through css filters on an image with jquery (in webkit)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to impart a wild and psychedelic flair to a webpage by changing the css-filter hue-rotate property on an image when the user loads the page. How do I get hue-rotate to change?  I was trying to base my solution on this answered question: [How to Cycle Through Background Colors on Hover with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16757416/how-to-cycle-through-background-colors-on-hover-with-jquery) which was answered in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xPqd/).

```
    var counter = 0;
var colors = [
    "#eeeeee",
    "#00ff00",
    "#ff0000",
    "#000000"];

var $div = $('#coloredDiv');
var interval;
$('#coloredDiv').mouseenter(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(changeColor, 1000);

}).mouseleave(function () {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});

function changeColor() {
    var color = colors.shift();
    colors.push(color);
    $div.css({
        "background-color": color
    });

}
```

But instead of changing the background color on a div I am trying to change hue-rotate on an image within a div. And yes, I want it to change onload, not onmouseenter. I am doing my testing in Chrome but Safari should also work since css filters have been implemented in webkit.

My attempt, which doesn't even try to incorporate the onload aspect yet:

```
var counter = 0;
var filters = [
    "hue-rotate(99deg)",
    "hue-rotate(22deg)",
    "hue-rotate(144deg)",
    "hue-rotate(270deg)";

var $div = $('#coloredDiv');
var interval;
$('#coloredDiv').mouseenter(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(changeFilter, 1000);

}).mouseleave(function () {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});

function changeFilter() 
    var filter = filters.shift();
    filters.push(filter);
    $div.css({

    "-webkit-filter": filter

    });

}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/izviz/57E4K/)

Answer (score 1):

You had a fair few syntax errors.
I've fixed these here: http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/57E4K/4/

```
var counter = 0;
var filters = ["hue-rotate(99deg)"
              , "hue-rotate(22deg)"
              , "hue-rotate(144deg)"
              , "hue-rotate(270deg)"];

var div = $('#coloredDiv');
var interval;

div.hover(function () {
    interval = window.setInterval(changeFilter, 1000);
}, function () {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
});

function changeFilter() {
    var filter = filters.shift();
    filters.push(filter);
    div.css({
        '-webkit-filter': filter
    });
}
```

Comment: A fair few, for sure. For a minute there, I thought it was some obscure inability of css filters. Very cool!